# Count by condition applied to the same column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

This is my data frame.

```
acc_index    veh_count    veh_type
001             1            1
002             2            1
002             2            2
003             2            1
003             2            2
004             1            1
005             2            1
005             2            3
006             1            2
007             2            1
007             2            2
008             2            1
008             2            1
009             3            1
009             3            1
009             3            2
```

acc_index is unique for each accident

veh_count shows how many vehicles are involved in one accident

veh_type shows the type of vehicles involved in an accident (1=bicycle, 2=car, 3=bus).

What I want to do is to count the number of accidents between cars and bicycles (so, **where veh_type=1 and veh_type=9 for the same acc_index**), even if there were more cars or bicycles involved, I still want to count it as one accident. How can I do that?

I tried to do it with the code below, but I get the count of all accidents involving cars or bikes, and I want to get **only the ones between them**.

```
df[(df['veh_count'] >=2) & (df.veh_type.isin(['1','2']))].groupby(['acc_index', 'veh_count', 'veh_type']).count()
```

I want to get something like this below, but also with the whole dataframe, and not only total sum.

```
acc_index    veh_count    veh_type     count
002             2            1           
002             2            2
                           count         1
003             2            1
003             2            2
                           count         1
007             2            1
007             2            2
                           count         1
009             3            1
009             3            1
009             3            2
                           count         1
                        total_count      4
```

If you have a better solution/idea, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can check `veh_type` for those of interest and groupby:

```
(df.assign(car=df.veh_type.eq(1),
          bike=df.veh_type.eq(2))  # change 2 to correct type
   [['acc_index','car','bike']]
   .groupby('acc_index')
   .any()
   .all(1).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
4
```

---

**Update**: If you want all the the rows:

```
s = (df.assign(car=df.veh_type.eq(1),
          bike=df.veh_type.eq(2))  # change 2 to correct type
   [['acc_index','car','bike']]
   .groupby('acc_index')
   .any()
   .all(1)
)

df[df['acc_index'].map(s)]
```

Output:

```
    acc_index  veh_count  veh_type
1           2          2         1
2           2          2         2
3           3          2         1
4           3          2         2
9           7          2         1
10          7          2         2
13          9          3         1
14          9          3         1
15          9          3         2
```

Comment: That works great, thanks!

If I want to also list all the 4 counted rows of the data frame, how can I do that?

Comment: An alternative: `pd.get_dummies(df.veh_type)[[1, 2]].groupby(df.acc_index).any().all(1).sum()`

Comment: Or: `df.groupby('acc_index')['veh_type'].apply(lambda g: not({1, 2} - {*g})).sum()`

Comment: @piRSquared thank you for the codes, both work! the second one is much faster though, do you maybe know the answer to my comment above?

Also, if I want to count and list all the bike-bike or car-car accidents, how can I do that?

Comment: Using @piRSquared with transform `df[df.groupby('acc_index')['veh_type'].transform(lambda g: not({1, 2} - {*g}))]`?

Comment: @piRSquared do you have some other solution in mind? 
this one last a bit long

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: ~50 000 rows, ~60 columns

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you, it's "fast' enough. Do you have an idea of how to easily count the bike-bike, or car-car accidents? If I do this `df[df.groupby('acc_index')['veh_type'].transform(lambda g: g==1)]` for bike-bike accidents, I just get the number of unique bike accidents, might be also with other types of vehicles, not just bike-bike accidents.

Comment: For bike-bike accidents, do a `value_counts` and filter those with count `>=2`?

Comment: I tried and failed, but I managed to do it with transform `df[df.groupby('acc_index')['acc_index'].transform('size') >= 2]` :)

Comment: That's only show you accidents involving more than 2 vehicles, regardless of type?

Comment: I separated a df with only bikes as veh_type (df_bikes), but now it's a problem that this shows all accidents with more than 2 bikes, even if it was an accident between 2 bikes and a car. It's messy and I have to solve it. I just want to count the accidents in which for the same acc_index I have only one type of veh_type (so only count veh_type==1 for bikes or only count veh_type=9 for cars). Do you have any idea?

Comment: This starts to get out of this question's context and no longer appropriate for comments. I suggest you post another question, link to this one if you like.