# Counting the occurence of data from 2 data frames (linked by an index) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have 2 large dataframes (these below are just extracts) containing information about road accidents, where `df_veh` contains details about vehicles and `df_ped` contains the count of pedestrians involved in each accident. `veh_type` shows the type of vehicles involved in an accident (1=bicycle, 2=car, 3=bus). They are linked with `acc_index` indicating unique accident.

```
veh_data = {'acc_index':  ['001', '002', '002', '003', '003', '004', '005', '005', '006',
                           '006', '007', '007', '008', '008', '008', '009', '009', '009'],
         'veh_type': ['1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '1', '2', '1', '1', 
                      '1', '1', '2', '2'] }

df_veh = pd.DataFrame (veh_data, columns = ['acc_index', 'veh_type'])       

ped_data = {'acc_index':  ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009'],
            'pedestrians': ['1', '2', '0', '1', '4', '3', '0', '1', '2'] }
df_ped = pd.DataFrame (ped_data, columns = ['acc_index', 'pedestrians'])
```

What I want to do is to count the number of accidents (BY UNIQUE `acc_index` ONLY ONCE):

1. between cars and bicycles (`veh_type==1` and `veh_type==2`)
2. between bicycles and pedestrians (`veh_type==1` and `pedestrians>=1`)
3. between cars and pedestrians (`veh_type==2` and `pedestrians>=1`)
4. between **only** cars (`veh_type==2` for the same acc_index)
5. between **only** bicycles (`veh_type==1` for the same acc_index)
6. between **only** pedestrians (`pedestrians>=1` for the same acc_index)

I tried to do it in different ways but in the end, I get different results so I am confused. For example, I tried to count bike-pedestrian accidents like this:

```
df_bikes = df_veh[df_veh['veh_type']==1].groupby('acc_index').sum().reset_index()
bike_ped = pd.merge(df_bikes, df_ped, how='outer', on='acc_index')
bike_ped[(bike_ped['veh_type']==1) & (bike_ped['pedestrians']>=1)].groupby(
    'acc_index').sum().reset_index()[['acc_index', 'veh_type', 'pedestrians']]
```

Another example, this is how I counted accidents between cars and bicycles thanks to comments in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286060/count-by-condition-applied-to-the-same-column-in-pandas). I believe this one is correct at least. I am trying to find the simplest way to do this (but also displaying the rows counted).

```
bike_car = df_veh[def_veh.groupby('acc_index')['veh_type'].
                transform(lambda g: not({1, 2} - {*g}))][['acc_index', 'veh_type']]
len(bike_car.groupby(['acc_index']).size().reset_index()))
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.** See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC, I wouldn't ask a question if I didn't already search for an answer or knew how to do it. In case you didn't see: _I tried to do it in different ways but in the end, I get different results so I am confused._
**Stack Overflow is exactly the place to ask a question like this, you might be an advanced programmer, but I am just a beginner, so give me a break.** I edited my question with other things I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider pivoting the vehicle data with `pivot_table`  that is joined with a `groupby` aggregation of pedestrians and then run needed `query()` calls where each row is a distinct `acc_index`:

```
veh_dict = {'1': 'bicycle', '2': 'car', '3': 'bus'}

pvt_df = (df_veh.assign(val = 1)
                .pivot_table(index = 'acc_index', 
                            columns = 'veh_type', 
                            values = 'val', 
                            aggfunc='sum')
                .set_axis([veh_dict[i] for i in list('123')], 
                          axis = 'columns',  
                          inplace = False)
                .join(df_ped.assign(pedestrians = lambda x: x['pedestrians'].astype('int'))
                            .groupby('acc_index')['pedestrians']
                            .sum()
                            .to_frame(),
                      how = 'outer'
                     )

         )

pvt_df
#            bicycle  car  bus  pedestrians
# acc_index
# 001            1.0  NaN  NaN            1
# 002            1.0  1.0  NaN            2
# 003            2.0  NaN  NaN            0
# 004            1.0  NaN  NaN            1
# 005            NaN  2.0  NaN            4
# 006            NaN  1.0  1.0            3
# 007            1.0  1.0  NaN            0
# 008            3.0  NaN  NaN            1
# 009            1.0  2.0  NaN            2
```

Queries

```
# BIKES AND CARS
pvt_df.query('(bicycle >= 1) & (car >= 1)')
#            bicycle  car  bus  pedestrians
# acc_index
# 002            1.0  1.0  0.0            2
# 007            1.0  1.0  0.0            0
# 009            1.0  2.0  0.0            2

# BIKES AND PEDESTRIANS
pvt_df.query('(bicycle >= 1) & (pedestrians >= 1)')
#            bicycle  car  bus  pedestrians
# acc_index
# 001            1.0  0.0  0.0            1
# 002            1.0  1.0  0.0            2
# 004            1.0  0.0  0.0            1
# 008            3.0  0.0  0.0            1
# 009            1.0  2.0  0.0            2

# CARS AND PEDESTRIANS
pvt_df.query('(car >= 1) & (pedestrians > 1)')
#            bicycle  car  bus  pedestrians
# acc_index
# 002            1.0  1.0  0.0            2
# 005            0.0  2.0  0.0            4
# 006            0.0  1.0  1.0            3
# 009            1.0  2.0  0.0            2

### ONLY CARS
pvt_df.query('(bicycle == 0) & (car >= 1) & (bus == 0) & (pedestrians == 0)')
# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [bicycle, car, bus, pedestrians]
# Index: []

### ONLY BICYCLES
pvt_df.query('(bicycle >= 1) & (car == 0) & (bus == 0) & (pedestrians == 0)')
#            bicycle  car  bus  pedestrians
# acc_index
# 003            2.0  0.0  0.0            0

### ONLY PEDESTRIANS
pvt_df.query('(bicycle == 0) & (car == 0) & (bus == 0) & (pedestrians >= 1)')   
# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [bicycle, car, bus, pedestrians]
# Index: []
```

Comment: I tried this with adjustments to my real dataset and it works perfectly for my needs. What was wrong in my method for counting only car or only bike accidents is that I didn't set all the other conditions to zero, so I kept getting the wrong numbers. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!